# Passing parameters by reference from C++ to x86 MASM

Tags: c++, assembly, masm

I'm trying to pass parameters by reference from C++ to a function written in assembly, but I can't seem to actually change the value within the assembly function. What am I doing wrong here?

```
void __declspec(naked) asmChange(int&){
  __asm{
    mov   [esp+4], 5
    ret
  }
}

int main (){
  int a = 12;
  cout << "Before: " << a << endl;
  asmChange(a);
  cout << "After: " << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the program above I'm simply trying to change the value of a variable. I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong here and can't seem to find any answers to my issue anywhere else online.

Comment: What do you expect to find at `esp+4`?  The previous value of a?  Or a pointer to a?  Cuz it looks like what you're doing is overwriting the pointer, not the value pointed at.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I'm expecting to find the parameter being passed. How would I go about not overwriting the pointer itself, but rather, the value at the pointer?

Comment: C++ references are just pointers that get implicitly dereferenced by the compiler.  In asm they're still pointers, so you're just overwriting the pointer local variable, not anything owned by the caller.

Comment: As usual, look at compiler-generated code for a function that writes to an int-reference:  https://godbolt.org/z/dGroYTahs

Comment: Oh, also, `mov [esp+4], 5` shouldn't assemble; the operand-size is ambiguous between byte, word, and dword.  Make sure you use `mov dword ptr [eax], 5` after loading the pointer into EAX, to make sure the high 3 bytes aren't left unmodified in case it defaults to byte.  A good assembler should error on this as ambiguous; real MASM probably does, but apparently MSVC's inline assembler doesn't.